# Exponential Equation - Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem to solve:

[image: Problem Example]

So I first setup the equation:

$$9000=5000(1+\frac{r}{365})^{365 \cdot 4}$$

Next I simplified the exponent and divided the accumulated value by the principal:

$$1.8=(1+\frac{r}{365})^{1460}$$

I then found the natural log of both sides so I could use the power rule to separate the exponent out.

$$\ln(1.8)=1460 \cdot ln(1+\frac{r}{365})$$

I could then divide both sides by $1460$.

$$\frac{\ln(1.8)}{1460}=ln(1+\frac{r}{365})$$

Now would I distribute the natural log to the $1$ and $\frac{r}{365}$?  Or would I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "distribute the logarithm" over a sum, so don't do that.

Instead the natural thing to do to make progress would be to take the exponential on both sides, which will cancel out the logarithm on the right and produce
$$ e^{\frac{\log 1.8}{1460}} = 1+\frac{r}{365} $$

---

For a quick-and-dirty approximation you could also use the approximation $\log(1+\alpha)\approx \alpha$ when $\alpha$ is small (as $r/365$ probably is) and get $r\approx \frac{365}{4\cdot 365}\log 1.8$. The accuracy of this is better than the uncertainty arising from whether or not interest is compounded on the leap day ...

Comment: So if I followed your instructions and I got: $$r=e^{\frac{\ln(1.8)}{1460}}-365$$  But I plugged this back into the original equation and my calculator did not yield the correct accumulated value.

Comment: @ProfessorStealth: Your algebra is wrong. Soving $A=1+r/B$ for $r$ should yield $r = B(A-1)$, not $r=A-B$.

Comment: So, would $r=365(e^{\frac{\ln(1.8)}{1460}}-1)$ be correct? My calculator still says it is incorrect.

Comment: @ProfessorStealth: Your calculator's a lying bastard then. I get $r\approx 0.147$, which plugged into your original formula gives $A=\$9000.855$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't distribute the natural log, but you can solve for 1 + r/365 and then solve for r.